# Compare two time stamp in custom class list android

Tags: java, android

I want to compare two time stamps using comparator, ex.. i need to compare this two time 08:30 AM and 11:00 PM in my object list for sorting objects by time.

Can anybody please suggest me, how i will do this task.

Thanks!

Comment: "using comparator" - you questioned your own answer or did you answer your own question?

Comment: but how i will compare this two time inside compare method

Answer (score 0):

```
public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2)
{
 // extract time i.e,  08:30 / 11:00 and AM / PM indicator from your timestamp. a simple split() could do it.
 // now if indicator1 > indicator2 return 1
// if indicator1 < indicator2 return -1
// if indicator1 == indicator2, convert time1 and time2 to minutes (lazy conversion) from 00:00 and return 1 if intTime1>intTime2. -1 otherwise
// use a ternery operator for the above if you eant to.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A timestamp is just a Long value that represents the number of seconds since the Epoch (January 1, 1970). You can use them the same as any other number.

So to build a comparator that returns the usual negative, 0, positive values, just do something like the following:

```
public int compare(Object val1, Object val2) {
    return (Long) val1 - (Long) val2;
}
```